# Is it possible to install earlier version of tensorflow on Kaggle TPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, kaggle, tpu

Kaggle TPU switched to tf 2.3.1.
But I need tf 2.2.0.

I tried:

```
!pip install tensorflow~=2.2.0
```

Tensorflow switches to 2.2.1. But I am getting an error:

> InvalidArgumentError: NodeDef expected inputs 'string' do not match 0
> inputs specified; Op ; attr=T:type; attr=tensor_name:string;
> attr=send_device:string; attr=send_device_incarnation:int;
> attr=recv_device:string; attr=client_terminated:bool,default=false;
> is_stateful=true>; NodeDef: {{node _Send}}

when calling:

```
tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()  # TPU detection
print('Running on TPU ', tpu.cluster_spec().as_dict()['worker'])
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
```

There is no such a problem on Google Colab.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is impossible. Refer to:

https://www.kaggle.com/questions-and-answers/195058